# Flat WSDL using CoreWCF

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, soap, wsdl

I would like my new CoreWCF SOAP service to generate a single-file WSDL (flat WSDL). Is there any way to do this?

Here is my minimized version of Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
{    
    options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    options.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 5800, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
        if (sUrl.Scheme == "https") listenOptions.UseHttps();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddServiceModelServices().AddServiceModelMetadata();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IServiceBehavior, 
UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior>();

var app = builder.Build();
var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);

app.UseServiceModel(builder =>
{
    builder.AddService<MyService>()
    .AddServiceEndpoint<MyService, IMyService>(binding,"MyService");
});

var serviceMetadataBehavior = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
serviceMetadataBehavior.HttpsGetEnabled = true;

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out it is simply present at service url ended by `?singlewsdl`
instead of just `?wsdl`.

So the answer is `https://localhost:5800/MyService?singlewsdl`

Comment: This was introduced in WCF 4.5 and it is great that CoreWCF has also support for it : 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-new?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Documented under the paragraph "Generating a Single WSDL document" in that article.

The single wsdl contains everything and does not use xsd:import to import in other content, such as data contracts which ?wsdl returns .